# Basic question about real-analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, analytic-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ to be a real-analytic function in the whole line. Then, we can write $f(x)$ as the (convergente) power series $$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n, \quad \hbox{where}\quad a_n:=\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!},
$$
where $f^{(n)}(0)$ denotes its $n$-th derivative evaluated at $x=0$. I am wondering if the following property is true: There exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all $n=0,1,2,...$ we have $$
\vert a_n\vert \leq \dfrac{C}{n!} \ ?
$$
At first glance I was thinking that this should be true, but then I kept thinking that I have no control on the growth of $f^{(n)}(0)$ as $n$ growths. However, since the series is convergent, $a_n$ should always goes to zero, so... but that doesn't mean that the decay-rate must to be of order $\tfrac{1}{n!}$, right? That is actually what motivated my question, the decay at rate $\tfrac{1}{n!}$. In other words (if you want), can exist a real-analytic function so that the sequence of $f^{n}(0)$ behaves as (for example) $$
f^{(n)}(0)=\dfrac{n!}{n^{10}} \quad \hbox{so that} \quad a_n=\dfrac{1}{n^{10}}?
$$
This should also produce a convergent series, at least for $x\in (-1,1)$ small right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A counterexample is
$$
 f(x) = xe^x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}
$$
where
$$
 n! a_n = \frac{n!}{(n-1)!} = n 
$$
is unbounded. Another example is
$$
 g(x) = e^{x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{n!}
$$
where for the even-indexed coefficients
$$
 (2n)!a_{2n} = \frac{(2n)!}{n!} = (n+1)(n+2)\ldots(2n)
$$
grows faster than any polynomial.

What you can say about the growth is that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = 0$ if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n $ is convergent for all $x \in \Bbb R$, this follows from the formula for the radius of convergence of a power series.

Comment: I don't understand, the sequece of $a_n$ decreases as $\tfrac{1}{n!}$, well, as $\tfrac{1}{(n-1)!}$. I don't understand why is this a counterexample. I don't even understand what are you trying to contradict

Comment: @W2S: You asked if $n! |a_n|$ is necessarily bounded by a constant $C$, and this is an example where it is not.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't understand before. Now I see what you did. Sorry. Yes, you are 100% right

Comment: One last question about your last statement. It seems that the answer of "zhw" contradicts the limit property you pointed out $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\vert a_n\vert^{1/n}=0$, doesn't it?

Comment: @W2S: There is no contradiction. If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ converges for all real $x$ then the radius of convergence is infinity and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = 0$. The function $f(x) = 1/(1+x)$ can be developed into a Taylor series at each point $x_0 \in \Bbb R$, but the radius of convergence is finite.

Answer (score 4):

The function $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ is real analytic on the whole line, but the Taylor series of $f$ centered at $0$ is

$$1-x^2+x^4- x^6 +\cdots.$$

Thus $|a_n|=1$ for all even $n.$