# One (a little bit more specific) question about real-analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, analytic-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ to be a real-analytic function in the whole line. Then, we can write $f(x)$ as the (convergente) power series $$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n, \quad \hbox{where}\quad a_n:=\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!},
$$
where $f^{(n)}(0)$ denotes its $n$-th derivative evaluated at $x=0$. [In a previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834878/basic-question-about-real-analytic-functions) I have asked if the sequence of coefficients $a_n$ always decays as $\sim\tfrac{1}{n!}$ when $n$ goes to $\infty$. After two great and basic counter-examples of another member I realize that this (too) strong property does not hold in general. However, as you can see below, both counterexamples still exhibits exponential decay! So I am wondering if the following weaker property holds: For any $m\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all $n=1,2,3,...$ we have $$
\vert a_n\vert \leq \dfrac{C}{n^m} \ ?
$$
Of course, this is a weaker statement than the one of my previous post (decay of order $\tfrac{1}{n!}$), and also weaker than exponential decay.

**Previous counter-examples:** For the sake of completeness let me copy-paste both previous counter-examples:

1.- $$
 f(x) = xe^x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n-1)!} \quad \implies  a_n = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} 
$$
2.- $$
 g(x) = e^{x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{n!} \quad \implies \quad a_{2n} = \frac{1}{n!}.
$$

**Last comment:** Notice that in both cases we have $$
\lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n\exp(n)=0.
$$

Comment: See zhw's counterexample to your previous post.

Comment: When you say real-analytic on the whole real line, do you mean that the Taylor series (centered at zero) converges on the whole real line? That is a MUCH stronger condition than just real analytic. For example, partitions of unity can be kind of weird.